# TYPO3 use parentRec in TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

With FLexform it is possible to get check a parent Field using

```
<displayCond>FIELD:parentRec.field:=:value</displayCond>
```

Can I use the same method for simple TCA (my child is type inline)?

```
'displayCond' => 'FIELD:parentRec.field:=:value',
```

This doesn't work for me.
TYPO3 version 8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `parentRec` is [limited to FlexForms](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/1ad185f32e63179dabb6d9634c1cd5c75bad51fb/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/FormDataProvider/EvaluateDisplayConditions.php#L455-L459).

Depending on your usecase this could be done with [`columnsOverrides`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Types/Index.html#columnsoverrides) together with [`overrideChildTca`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Properties/InlineOverrideChildTCa.html).

Comment: This works but doesn't solve my problem. If I use the condition
`FIELD:layout:IN:11,12` the layout value of the child element is checked and not the layout field from the parent